# Effect of temperature on specific weight

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, density, fluid-statics, weight

How much of an impact has a temperature difference when the specific weight of an object in water is measured, e.g. the weight of a mussel in seawater. Would the two scenarios yield the same specific weight and if not is there a way to correct the specific weight for the temperature difference?

1. Seawater 11 degree Celsius and mussel 11 degree Celsius
2. Seawater 21 degree Celsius and mussel 11 degree Celsius

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the temperature of the mussel has not changed during the course of the measurement, obviously not. You have to correct  for the variation of the density of seawater.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Dr S T Lakshmikumar. Would the specific weight stay constant if the temperatures of the water and the mussel change at the same rate, so that the temperature difference stayed the same e.g. 10 - 15 and 15 - 20 degree Celsius)?

Comment: Not likely. You would need the changes in densities of sea water and the mussel to match and there is no physical reason why they should